# Hindu marriage in regards to the new moon

Tags: astrology, superstitions, amavasya

Does a girl born on a new moon have to get married to a guy born on a new moon too? They say if a girl is born on a new moon and marries someone born on other days except the new moon, the groom has a shorter life and dies early.

Is there any truth behind this?

Comment: Girl born on new moon day is considered lucky and considered Lakshmi devi.

Answer (score 1):

There is no truth in it.

Amavasya is condition of [Chandra yuti Surya](http://www.barbarapijan.com/bpa/Graha_Yoga_Combi/Chandra_yuti_Surya_12Razi.htm) in Jyotish. This means that the Moon and the Sun are at the same degrees.

This also implies that, in the person's chart, Sun and Moon will be in the same Rashi, Nakshatra and Bhava.

This condition is also called as moudhya-Chandra or a [combust](http://www.barbarapijan.com/bpa/graha/graha_combust_moudhya.htm) moon.

It essentially implies that some of the traits that Moon implies in a person's chart will be not so powerful.

The extent of this will again vary from person to person depending your Lagna; the Bhava, Nakshatra and Rashi where the Sun and the Moon are sitting e.g if this combination is happening in Karka Rashi (Cancer) which is a sign ruled by Moon, the effect of moudhya will be lesser.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not a new moon, but a day (*tithi*) before that, i.e., *Chaturdashi* which is considered inauspicious birth for a female.

**Such a girl is termed as Viṣakanyakā.**

This follows from the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa

> [Verse 6.1.61.6-10](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc493371.html)
>
> ब्राह्मणा ऊचुः ।
>  या कन्या प्राप्नुयाज्जन्म चित्रासंस्थे दिवाकरे
> ।
>  चंद्रे वापि चतुर्दश्यां सा भवेद्विषकन्यका ॥ ६ ॥
>
> > The Brāhmaṇas said:
> >
> > 6. **If a girl is born when the Sun is in the constellation Citrā or the Moon in the fourteenth lunar day, she will become a Viṣakanyakā (a
> >    poison girl).**
>
> ---
>
> यस्तस्याः प्रतिगृह्णाति पाणिं पार्थिवसत्तम ।
>  षण्मासाभ्यंतरे
> मृत्युं स प्राप्नोति नरो ध्रुवम् ॥ ७ ॥
>
> > 7. **A man who grasps her hand in marriage, O excellent king, will certainly meet with his death within six months**.
>
> ---
>
> यस्मिन्सा जायते हर्म्ये षण्मासाभ्यंतरे च तत् ।
>  करोति विभवैर्हीनं
> धनदस्याप्यसंशयम् ॥ ८ ॥
>
> > 8. She will render the mansion wherein she is born, even if it be that of Kubera, a place devoid of riches within six months.
>
> ---
>
> सेयं तव सुता राजन्यथोक्ता विष कन्यका ।
>  पैतृकं श्वाशुरीयं च
> हनिष्यति गृहद्वयम् ॥ ९ ॥
>
> > 9. Such is, O king, your daughter who is called a Viṣakanyakā. She will destroy the two families, viz. that of parents and that of her
> >    father-in-law.
>
> ---
>
> तस्मादिमां परित्यज्य सुखी भव नराधिप ।
>  श्रद्दधासि वचोऽस्माकं हित
> मुक्तं यदि प्रभो ॥ १० ॥
>
> > 10. Hence, do be happy, O king, by abandoning her if you have faith in our words, spoken by us for your good, O Lord.
>
> English Translation by G.V. Tagare

So, a girl born on the fourteenth day of the lunar day, *and not* on the New Moon is considered inauspicious, as per the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa.