# Marrying people born on new moon day (amāvāsyā)?

Tags: culture, marriage, tradition, astrology

I was told marrying people that are born on *amāvāsyā* (new moon day) will bring harm to your life; you can even die because of their *grahan* (sin attached to them?) – is this claim true?

Comment: whoever said these bogus things, ask them for reference from Hindu scripture(religious text book of hinduism) or for that matter from - any book?

Comment: How do u say that it's all bogus? Are u a pundit? @zaxebo1

Comment: I have answered it here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7416/hindu-marriage-in-regards-to-the-new-moon/26381#26381